# Python command prompt executed the second command before executing the first command

Tags: python, windows, cmd, cd

I wrote a python script where in one step it has to open a '**NEW**' terminal 'cmd.exe' and then should change the directory and run a second command in the changed directory.

```
proc = os.system('start cmd /K "cd C:\\Users\\..\\emulator && [the command I want to execute in the changed directory]"')
```

When executing in IDLE Shell, the command is working as expected but when I run my .py python code, it ends up running the second command before the first command to change the directory, hence the second command fails.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Why using `start`, which is a command internal to `cmd.exe`? Have you tried skipping it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Windows [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command does not wait for the specified command to finish, so it's possible for the other command you want to execute to (randomly) start before the current working directory has been changed. You can add a `/wait` argument to it (the `start` command) which should prevent that from happening.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was wondering what the cause was!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question of why that is happening.  But, if you use the newer [`subprocess` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), you can pass a working directory as a parameter:

```py
subprocess.run('my command', cwd='C:\emulator')
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment without more clarification from the OP, but replacing `os.system` with `subprocess` is almost *always* the right thing to do.

Comment: subprocess.run('my command', cwd='C:\emulator') This method is running the command in the same terminal where my python code is running. But I needed to perform this in a 'NEW'or separate terminal

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the `shell=True` option.